# What to do with Mbutil Export for TileMill and Mapbox

Tags: openlayers

Hey all. Im just trying to figure out how to use my mbtile directory export. My files are located in a local directory "/mytiles". How can I configure this to use my custom layer?

```
  <head>
    <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var map;
      OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
      OpenLayers.ImgPath = "http://js.mapbox.com/theme/dark/";
      function init(){

        // Customize the values below to change the tileset.
        // This information is available on each tileset page.
        var layername = 'world-light';
        var file_extension = 'png';

        // Build the map
        var options = {
          projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
          displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
          units: "m",
          numZoomLevels: 12,
          maxResolution: 156543.0339,
          maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(
            -20037500,
            -20037500,
            20037500,
            20037500
          )
        };
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

        // Layer definitions
        var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS(
          "MapBox Layer",
          [ "http://a.tile.mapbox.com/","http://b.tile.mapbox.com/",
            "http://c.tile.mapbox.com/","http://d.tile.mapbox.com/" ],
          { 'layername': layername, 'type': file_extension }
        );

        // Add layers to the map
        map.addLayers([ layer ]);

        // Set the map's initial center point
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 1);
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, see the part of the code that includes `http://a.tile.mapbox.com/`. Replace that with the hostname or local name of your computer - this might be `http://localhost/` or `http://mycomputer.com/`, etc. Then replace layername with the name of your layer.

Since this is using a TMS layer, you'll need to create a directory named `1.0.0` that'll lie in between these two things - you'll need to move your tiles there, if they're in a directory called `mydirectory`. The result would be like `http://localhost/1.0.0/mydirectory`.

So, if the URL of a tile is `http://localhost/1.0.0/mydirectory/0/0/0.png`, you'd have

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS(
  "MapBox Layer",
  [ "http://localhost/" ],
  { 'layername': 'mydirectory', 'type': 'png' }
);
```

You can consult [OpenLayers.org TMS](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/TMS-js.html) for complete documentation of the layer  type.

Comment: I'm having trouble making this work by your suggested method.  I was under the impression that "layername" and "file_extension" were variables taken from earlier in the code.  You've replaced the "layername" variable with a directory name.  I'd love to make this work with data served by my own tilestream host.  What am I missing?